# Why is my io.on('connect', function (socket) { //functions... }); server side function firing the same number of times as I have open tabs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

//index.html - Static
//It links to different chat rooms

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Events</title>
    </head>
    <body>
     <ul>
         <li><a href="events/superbowl">Super Bowl</a></li>
         <li><a href="events/world-series">World Series</a></li>
         <li><a href="events/world-cup">World Cup</a></li>
     </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

//events.html - Client Side
It connects and and sends messages between each room appropriately, but for each browser tab I open it connects the amount of times as the number of open tabs. Therefore, my (lets say) 3rd tab connects it will send 3 messages in the chat while my 1st tab that is in the same room would only send one.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Event Chat</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
          * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
          form { background: #999; padding: 3px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
          form input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; margin-right: .5%; }
          form button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: none; padding: 10px; }
          #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
          #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
          #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
     </style>
  </head>
    <body>
        <ul id="messages"></ul>
        <form action="">
            <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8008/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script> 
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function(){

                //***** Chat messages *****//
                var socket = io();

                $('form').submit(function(){
                    socket.emit('chatMsg', $('#m').val());
                    $('#m').val('');

                    return false;
                });

                socket.on('chatMsg', function (msg){
                    $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
                });

               //***** End chat messages *****//

               //***** On connection *****//

               socket.on('connect', function() {
                   console.log('attempt to join room');
               });

               //***** End on connection *****//

           });
       </script>
   </body>
```

//main.js - Server Side

```
var app  = require('express')(),
server = require('http').Server(app),
io   = require('socket.io')(server),
room;

    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile('index.html');
    });

    app.get('/events/*', function (req, res) {
        res.sendfile('event.html');

    io.on('connect', function (socket) {
        console.log('connected');
        room = req.params[0];
        socket.join(room);

        socket.on('chatMsg', function (msg) {
            io.in(room).emit('chatMsg', msg);
        });

        socket.on('disconnect', function () {
            socket.leave(room)
        });
     });    
  });

server.listen('8008', function () {
    console.log('Listening on *:8008');
});
```

Comment: Its because they share the same session I believe, if you open chrome and firefox and test with the both of those you will get different results.

Comment: Unfortunately, I receive the same results. I should just enable sessions via express. I have to do it anyway and it's probably the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try placing the io-handling outside of `app.get('/events/*', function(req, res) {...})`.
As is every time a user requests something at `/events/*`, you get a new `connect` event.

Comment: That's it. Thank you.  I just need to access the req parameter now within my io handling.